# can I runtime.exec() a 64-bit program from 32-bit java?

Tags: java, windows, 32bit-64bit

My operaion  system is windows 7 64bit.
I want to know if it is possible to run a 64-bit program via 32-bit JRE.

I do a simple test:
"engine.exe" is 64bit, but JRE is 32bit.

```
 String cmdStr = "C:\\RLX\\VM\\bin\\engine.exe";
 Process ps = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdStr);
 k = ps.exitValue();
```

I found that the "engine.exe" can't be launched, However the "engine.exe" can be launched via 64bit JRE.

ps.exitValue() return "-1073741515".

Are there any ways to invoke a 64-bit program via 32-bit JRE?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Any particular reason to use a 32 bit JRE?

Comment: It ought to work.  Is that the real path to the executable?

Comment: My project used 32bit JRE and it need invoke a external windows tool , this external tool is developed by other people. In the past this external tool is 32bit, but now it  also has a 64bit version. I need to make my project support the 64bit version.

Comment: If the 32bit JRE can invoke a 64bit external command, I guess that the problem  may come from the external command.

Comment: That is the real path.  The "ps.exitValue()" return "-1073741515". I don't know  what  the value means.

Comment: `STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND`, um, perhaps something to do with the current directory?  Or Java might be doing something odd with the environment variables.